# XSLT and Googles custom XML site search

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using Googles XML custom site search ([Google XML sitesearch](http://www.google.com/cse/docs/resultsxml.html)) and I am using XSLT in .NET to transform the results to HTML. I have a few question regarding XSLT.

1) Google will return something similar to the following

```
<GSP VER="3.2">
  <PARAM name="start" value="0" />
  <PARAM name="num" value="10" />
  <RES>
    <R>
      <PageMap>
        <DataObject>
          <Attribute name="Rating" value="4.5" />
          <Attribute name="RatingCount" value="743" />  
        </DataObject>
      </PageMap>
    </R>
  </RES>
</GSP>
```

I am wondering the following:

How would I get the value of one of the PARAM (i.e. Start or num)?
And how would I get the value of one of the DataObject's Attributes?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Never use `//` when the schema is known.**

To get start value use:

```
/GSP/PARAM[@name='start']/@value
```

To get num parameter:

```
/GSP/PARAM[@name='num']/@value
```

To get rating:

```
/GSP/RES/R/PageMap/DataObject/Attribute[@name='Rating']/@value
```

Comment: Well, that's why I show two examples. I'm pretty sure in concrete XSLT stylesheet it would be based on concrete context. However you're right in long term prospective, this clarification is helpful.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure in concrete XSLT stylesheet it would be based on concrete context". That's a fatal omission. Novices usually don't understand "concrete context" thing.

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath you could refer to these values like this:

```
/GSP/PARAM[@name='num']/@value
```

For DataObject Attributes it would be

```
//DataObject/Attribute[@name='Rating']/@value
```

However you need to clarify in which context you need to get these values as expressions might me shorter in most cases (I used full path).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use keys in case if params in this sample needs to be accessed by names from various contexts. Using keys will also protect your sources from repeating xpath again and again.

```
<!-- Key declaration -->    
<xsl:key name="gsp-param" match="/GSP/PARAM/@value" use="../@name"/>

<xsl:template name="some-template">
    <!-- Get key value in unknown context -->
    <xsl:value-of select="key('gsp-param', 'num')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yeah, novice with poor english :\

Comment: +1 Good advice, only in case you use this expressions many times.